# send email to all registered users when post expires

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, email, wp-mail

I have a function which, when a post is published inside a CPT after three days the page is redirected to another URL/PERMALINK.

This is the code:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'check_the_date_for_stats');

function check_the_date_for_stats() {
  if ( is_singular('debate') ) { // adjust myCPT with your real cpt name
    $pl = get_permalink( get_queried_object() ); // permalink
    $is_stats = array_key_exists( 'stats', $GLOBALS['wp_query']->query ); // is stats?
    $is_cm = array_key_exists( 'comments', $GLOBALS['wp_query']->query ); // is comments?
    $ts = mysql2date('Ymd', get_queried_object()->post_date_gmt ); // post day
    $gone = ($ts + 3) < gmdate('Ymd'); // more than 3 days gone?
    if ( $gone && ( ! $is_stats && ! $is_cm ) ) {
       // more than 3 days gone and not is stats => redirect to stats
       wp_redirect( trailingslashit($pl) . '/stats' );
       exit();
    } elseif( ! $gone && ( $is_stats || $is_cm ) ) {
       // we are in 3 days frame and trying to access to stats => redirect to post
       wp_redirect( $pl );
       exit();
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible, after 3 days are gone to send an email with a standard message to all registered users, if so how can I do this ? 
I know this function:

`<?php wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments ); ?>`
but I don't know how can I link this with my function to send an email to all registered users after three days have passed.

Can someone give me some hints on how can I achieve this ? 
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do this if you have too many registered users on the site. Below is the edited portion from your code.

```
} elseif( ! $gone && ( $is_stats || $is_cm ) ) {
   // we are in 3 days frame and trying to access to stats => redirect to post

   // Start the code to send the emails
   $subject = '3 days have passed';
   $users = get_users();
   foreach($users as $user) {
      $message = 'Hello '.$user->display_name.', '.PHP_EOL;
      $message .= 'The 3 days have past since the post.';
      wp_mail($user->user_email, $subject, $message);
   }
   // End the code to send the emails

   wp_redirect( $pl );
   exit();
}
```